# The boundary of the cylinder over $\Delta_q$ consists of the cylinder over the boundary of $\Delta_q$ and the upper and lower faces of the cylinder.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[Reference](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/pamphlets/algtop.pdf)

I was reading a proof of homotopy invariance of homology and arrived at a statement which I simply could not prove: *Here, by a map, I shall imply that it is continuous for brevity*

> *Proof:* Let $\Delta_{q} \times I$ denote the cylinder over $\Delta_{q} .$ As usual, the vertices of $\Delta_{q}$ will be denoted by $e_{0}, \ldots, e_{q} .$ Let the vertices of $\Delta_{q} \times(0)$ be denoted by $l e_{0}, \ldots, l e_{q}$ and the vertices of $\Delta_{q} \times(1)$ by $u e_{0}, \ldots, u e_{q} .$ For each $i=0,1,2, \ldots, q,$ we denote the linear map of $\Delta_{q+1}$ in $\Delta_{q} \times I$ which takes $e_{j}$ into $l e_{j}$ for $j \leq i$ and $e_{j}$ into $u e_{j-1}$ for $j>i$ by $f_i.$ Clearly it is a singular $(q+1)$
> simplex of $\Delta_{q} \times I.$ Consider the singular $(q+1)$ -chain $\gamma_{q}$ of $\Delta_{q} \times I$ given by
> $$
> \gamma_{q}=\sum_{0 \leq i \leq q}(-1)^{i}f_i.
> $$

Here, $e_0,..,e_q$ are the canonical co-ordinates, that is, unit vectors, in a $q+1$ dimensional space, $\Delta_q$ is the standard $q-$simplex given by the set $\{(x_0,...,x_q)\in\mathbb{R}^{q+1}:x_i\geq 0, \sum_ix_i=1\},$ and $f_i$ is the singular $q+1-$simplex of $\Delta_q\times I$ for each $i=0,1,...,q$  given by the explicit map $$f_i(x)=\sum_{0\leq i\leq j}x_j\cdot le_j+\sum_{i< j\leq q+1}x_j\cdot ue_{j-1},\quad (x_0,x_1,...,x_{q+1})=x\in\Delta_{q+1}.$$

> The map $\epsilon_{q}^{i}: \Delta_{q-1} \rightarrow \Delta_{q}$ gives a map $\bar{\epsilon}_{q}^{i}: \Delta_{q-1} \times I \rightarrow$
> $\Delta_{q} \times I$ defined by $\bar{\epsilon}_{q}^{i}(\lambda, t)=\left(\epsilon_{q}^{i} (\lambda), t\right), \lambda \in \Delta_{q-1}, t \in I .$ This in turn
> induces a homomorphism $C_n\left(\bar{\epsilon}_{q}^{i}\right): C_n\left(\Delta_{q-1} \times I\right) \rightarrow C_n\left(\Delta_{q} \times I\right) $ for all $n.$ We denote
> by $\gamma_{q}^{(i)}$ the image of the $q$ -chain $\gamma_{q-1}$ by $C_{q}\left(\bar{\epsilon}_{q}^{i}\right) .$ We can verify that
> $$(*) \quad \partial_{q+1}(\gamma_{q})=g-g'-\sum_{0 \leq i \leq q}(-1)^{i} \gamma_{q}^{(i)}$$
> where $g$ (resp. $g'$) denotes the singular $q$ -simplex of $\Delta_{q} \times I$ which sends $e_{i}$ to $u e_{i}\left(\text {resp. } e_{i} \text { to } l e_{i}\right)$ for $0 \leq i \leq q$ and which is linear.

Here, the map $\epsilon_q^i:\Delta_{q-1}\rightarrow \Delta_q$ is the map defined as $(x_0,...,x_{q-1})\mapsto (x_0,...,x_{i-1},0,x_i,...,x_{q-1}),$ or more explicitly as $(x_0,...,x_{q-1})\mapsto \sum_{0 \leq j \leq i} x_{j} e_{j}+\sum_{i < j \leq q-1} x_{j} e_{j+1}.$

$C_n(X)$ is the group of singular $n$-chains of a topological space $X$ and is the free abelian group generated by the singular $n-$simplices of $X$.

The induced homomorphism $C(\bar{\epsilon}_q^i)$ will be the homomorphism such that $f\mapsto \bar{\epsilon}_q^i\circ f$ for all $f\in C_n(\Delta_{q-1}\times I).$

We know that the boundary homomorphism $\partial_q:C_q(X)\rightarrow C_{q-1}(X)$ is the extended map of mapping $f\mapsto \sum_{0\leq i\leq q}(-1)^i f^{[i]}$ for all $f:\Delta_q\rightarrow X$ *(it is extendable as $C_q(X)$ is a free abelian group with the $q-$simplices making a basis)*, where $f^{[i]}$ is the $i^{th}$ face of the map $f$ given by the map $f\circ \epsilon_q^i.$

The problem is, I cannot prove statement $(*);$ I know that:

$$\partial_{q+1}(\gamma_q)=\sum_{0\leq i\leq q+1}(-1)^i\gamma_q^{[i]}=\sum_{0\leq i\leq q+1}(-1)^i\sum_{0\leq j\leq q}(-1)^j(f_j\circ \epsilon_{q+1}^i),$$

but the RHS is nowhere in sight, especially with the functions $g,g'$. I am quite dumbfounded, and still very new to these concepts, so any help would be very, very appreciated. Thank you so much!

Also, the author gives a geometric interpretation of this as:

> The above formula makes precise the following geometric fact which is intuitively clear: the boundary of the cylinder over the simplex $\Delta_{q}$ consists of the cylinder over the boundary of $\Delta_{q}$ and the upper and lower faces of the cylinder, with proper signs.

Comment: I think the notation is hiding a lot of the simplicity of this statement. May I suggest looking at Hatcher for a proof, and comparing? The idea is exactly the same but the notation is clearer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that... I was originally following hatcher till my professor switched, I will go back the book

Comment: No problem. What book is this from? My current best guess is that the $\sum_{0 \leq i \leq q+1} \gamma_q^{(i)}$ has one of the $g$’s as it’s $q+1$’th term. That seems to make sense to me, but that leaves the other $g$. Trying to think if there’s an indexing error somewhere. Actually I think I have it, and I’ll write it down once I get to a computer.

Comment: Okay thank you! This is from a pamphlet made by TIFR, which I will attach now.